# Spin 1/2 finite-difference field simulator?

Tags: software, wavefunction, spinors

Is there a finite-difference field simulator for spin 1/2 fields, something like meep for electromagnetism (spin 1)?   Looking for something free (GNU, MIT or other open/free style license) and easy to set up and run simulations for educational purposes, not a heavy research tool.

Comment: My weak little experimentalist brain is failing to think of an example of a fermionic field...

Comment: It's not you, @dmckee, it's nature.

Comment: @dmckee: I'd consider anything described by a quantum field theory to be a field.  Sure e.g. the electron/positron field has some different properties than the E&M field, but I don't see why it shouldn't be called a field.  As for finite-difference field simulators, wouldn't lattice QCD or QED simulations count?

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that finite difference methods are fine for solving the equations of motion of a classical field, but quantum fields are like, operator-valued distributions or some such nonsense. Lattice QCD or QED calculations are done by Monte Carlo sampling, and fermions generically have a sign problem.